# Sum amount by type of food in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm new to SQL, I'm using SQL Server 2008.

In my database I have 3 tables

1. Table `Type`
2. Table `Invoice`
3. Table `Item`

This is my SQL command to get sum amount:

```
SELECT 
   tbl_type.type,
   ((tbl_item.price * qty) - (tbl_item.price * qty * discount)) as totalAfter,
   tbl_inv.dateInv
FROM 
   tbl_type, tbl_item, tbl_inv 
WHERE 
   tbl_inv.dateInv = '2013-03-26 00:00:00' 
   AND tbl_inv.id = tbl_item.id_invoice 
   AND tbl_type.id = tbl_item.id_type
ORDER BY 
   tbl_inv.dateInv;
```

So when I run my query it will return

```
CHICKEN        46.000000    2013-03-26 00:00:00.000
MEAT            3.000000    2013-03-26 00:00:00.000
CHICKEN        69.000000    2013-03-26 00:00:00.000
CHICKEN        46.000000    2013-03-26 00:00:00.000
CHICKEN        69.000000    2013-03-26 00:00:00.000
MEAT            4.500000    2013-03-26 00:00:00.000
```

But how to do like this?

```
CHICKEN       230.000000    2013-03-26 00:00:00.000
MEAT            7.500000    2013-03-26 00:00:00.000
```

I will get error

> Column 'tbl_item.price' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

when I use `GROUP BY tbl_type.type` in my SQL

Thanks for help.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was discontinued with the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **20 years** ago)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT tbl_type.type,SUM((tbl_item.price * qty) - (tbl_item.price * qty * discount)) as totalAfter ,tbl_inv.dateInv
FROM tbl_type,tbl_item,tbl_inv 
WHERE tbl_inv.dateInv = '2013-03-26 00:00:00' AND tbl_inv.id=tbl_item.id_invoice AND tbl_type.id=tbl_item.id_type
Group by tbl_type.type,tbl_inv.dateInv
ORDER BY tbl_inv.dateInv,tbl_type.type;
```